# Redefining contentsline using hyperref

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I'm using LaTeX writing my bachelor thesis and I have some issues with the `hyperref` package.

I use a LaTeX document provided by my university that has a lot of stuff regarding citation styles, listings, numbering etc. already predefined according to university's guidelines. Trying to use `hyperref`, I ran into a problem with captions in float environments like tables and figures. Error message is:

```
! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
```

I tried to make a minimal example reproducing the error, spend a few hours on google and here on stackexchange and the problem seems to be the redefinition of `\contentsline` and `\numberline` provided by my university:

```
\let\jbcontentsline\contentsline
\renewcommand{\contentsline}[3]{\jbcontentsline{##1}{##2}{##3}\vspace{0.25\baselineskip}}
\let\jbnumberline=\numberline%
\renewcommand{\numberline}[2]{\jbnumberline{Abbildung ##1:}{##2}}
```

So, as far as I understood, this redefinitions do not work because `hyperref` also redefined those commands. Is there a way to adapt the code to make it work with `hyperref`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you please name the used style or give a link to it? Without knowing your used document class it is hard to help you. A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be helpful.

Comment: The document class is scrreprt. But I don't think the style is available on the internet somewhere.

Comment: With no MWE, this is I'm afraid unclear.

Comment: Unfortunately this question has been closed, while at least some issues can be solved. 
Therefore I give my answer as comment: 
1. First load hyperref, *then* change `\contentsline` and `\numberline`. 
2. Hyperref uses `\numberline` with four (4) parameters, not with only three (3)! 
3. There is a spurious "=" in your code. 
4. Better: (to be continued)

Comment: (continuation)
`\RequirePackage{letltxmacro}[2010/09/02]\relax
\GlobalLetLtxMacro{\jbcontentsline}{\contentsline}\relax
\renewcommand{\contentsline}[4]{\jbcontentsline{##1}{##2}{##3}{##4}\vspace{0.25\baselineskip}}\relax
\GlobalLetLtxMacro{\jbnumberline}{\numberline}\relax
\renewcommand{\numberline}[2]{\jbnumberline{Abbildung ##1:}{##2}}\relax`. 
(Instead of `\relax` a new line should be used, which is not possible in comments.) 
That should fix at least some error(message)s.